# Custom width for chapter

Tags: titlesec, geometry, marginnote

In my current `LaTeX` project, I want to have a wide margin next to my text to add notes there. But the problem is that the chapter heading looks a bit "too short". Especially with long headlines it looks strange if a line break has to be made so early. Is it possible to extend the width so that the title is also above the margin notes?

[image: Chapter title is a bit too short]

I am using titlesec and marginnote.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=6.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=15mm, footskip=15mm,marginparwidth=3.5cm,marginparsep=0.5cm,asymmetric]{geometry}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\titleformat{\chapter}%
  {\sffamily\bfseries\Huge}{\thechapter.}{10pt}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a long chapter title}

\marginnote{\lipsum}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following allows the chapter titles to cover the entire width of your text block and margin paragraph by using a `\parbox` of that width and letting it silently overprinting the text block using `\rlap`.

I'd also suggest to allow ragged section titles as generally justification works poor for short paragraphs (which headings effectively are).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=6.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=15mm, footskip=15mm,marginparwidth=3.5cm,marginparsep=0.5cm,asymmetric]{geometry}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\titleformat{\chapter}%
{\sffamily\bfseries\Huge}{\rlap{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}{\raggedright\thechapter.\
#1}}}{10pt}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a long chapter title that grows longer and longer and longer}

\marginnote{\lipsum}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works with my MWE, but unfortunately, it breaks my actual LaTeX Project. I think, the [explicit] may be the cause for that. Is it possible to only change this for chapter?

Comment: @JimYe I'm afraid not, afaik, you can only activate that globally... But let me dig a bit.

Comment: The alternative is that you just put a `#1` after your before code for your setups of `\section` and so on.

Comment: If you want to retain the hanging indent of the sectioning numbers I can provide that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not the same as your output,have a look to the following approach:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=6.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=15mm, footskip=15mm,marginparwidth=3.5cm,marginparsep=0.5cm,asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\titleformat{\chapter}%
  {\sffamily\bfseries\Huge}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\thechapter.\hspace{10pt}}}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a long chapter title}

\marginnote{\lipsum}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]